# Tab completion doesn't work for file arguments to certain commands

Tags: bash, auto-completion

I have a directory containing a disk image, let's call it "image.dd".  In reality it is a much longer name, thus the desire to table complete the name by typing the first character and hitting tab to get the rest.  There are only a few files in the directory, each starting with a unique letter.

If I type `ls i<TAB>` the command completes properly to `ls image.dd`.

But if I type `fdisk -l i<TAB>` nothing happens.  This is really annoying.  I get the impression that tab completion is snooping on my command and seeing the "fdisk" part and saying, "Oh, you can't fdisk a regular file, so I'm going to ignore your request to autocomplete the file, even though it is actually there."

Of course when I manually type in the name it works, I *can* fdisk a file when it's a disk image, so how can I get tab completion to just work?

Using Ubuntu 16.04, bash version is 4.3.42.

Comment: Tab completion works for me on a 14.04 server installation in both examples you've given.

Comment: @Arronical updated question to include versions I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete rules for fdisk are stored in the file `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/fdisk`. The rules there defines that it will expand to block devices. To overwrite this setting in your current enviroment - you could do:

```
complete -F _filedir_xspec fdisk
```

You could add this to your `.bashrc` file.